# show or hide pagination icons based on input value using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs for building pagination. It is having one 'textbox(directly enter the page value)' and 'next' and 'prev' icons,

The icons should be show and hide based on the input page value.

this is my code,

### HTML

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="currentPage1" value=""/>                          
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-hide="prevPageDisabled()" ng-click="prevPage();"> <img src="img/previous.png" /></a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-hide="nextPageDisabled()" ng-click="nextPage();"> <img src="img/next.png" /></a>
```

### controller

```
$scope.currentPage1 = 1;
$scope.itemsPerPage1 = 10;    

$scope.pageCount = function() {      
      return Math.ceil($scope.results.length/$scope.itemsPerPage1);
    };
$scope.nextPage = function() {     
      if ($scope.currentPage1 < $scope.pageCount()) {        
        $scope.currentPage1++;
      }
    };

    $scope.prevPage = function() {
      if ($scope.currentPage1 > 0) {        
        $scope.currentPage1--;
      }
    };
    //prev page disabled
    $scope.prevPageDisabled = function() {      
      return $scope.currentPage1 === 1 ? "true" : "";
    };
    //next page disabled
    $scope.nextPageDisabled = function() {      
      return $scope.currentPage1 === $scope.pageCount() ? "true" : "";
    };
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `prevPageDisabled` and `nextPageDisabled` functions are called once when scope is compiled. Consequent `nextPage` and `prevPage` calls does not make `prevPageDisabled` and `nextPageDisabled` function values.

What you need is to bind the condition to scope variables directly. instead of making function calls:

> ```
> <input type="text" ng-model="currentPage1" value=""/>                          
>  <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-hide="currentPage1 === 1" ng-click="prevPage();"> <img src="img/previous.png" /></a>
>  <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-hide="currentPage1 === pageCount" ng-click="nextPage();"> <img src="img/next.png" /></a>
> ```